# False Algebraic Solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I sort of stumbled across something that I thought someone may be able to put to use. I was reading a book recently for undergrad math students and there was a section that contained common errors and one such example in the book is:

$x^2+5x+6=8 \rightarrow (x+3)(x+2)=8 \rightarrow x=-2,-3$

The book goes on to point out that this is wrong because it's of the form:

$ab=K \space$; where $K$ is constant and $a,b\in R$

Of which we can construct an infinite number of solutions. And I agree with that. But, I was thinking, there must be some relationship between the function and those values. And there is: any binomials that a quadratic can be factored into will provide solutions where, if

$x=l,m$ ; where $l,m$ are the seemingly erroneous solutions, then

$f(l),f(m)=-(K)$

Example: Using the above problem from the book (rearrange)...

$f(x)=x^2+5x-2$

$f(-3)=-8$

$f(-2)=-8$

Not only is this true, but you could manipulate the constant any way desired to obtain other symmetric points on the graph of this function. This is based on the transformation of the function where the x-values would provide a zero which is:

$ab-K=0$

This may seem like potentially useless information. But it implies that for more difficult equations the quadratic formula would not be required to find the behavior of the function. Example:

$2x^2+15x+23$

Instead of using the quadratic formula:

$2x^2+15x+18=-5 \rightarrow (2x+3)(x+6)=-5$

So $f(-6),f(-3/2)=5$ in our original function.

This process works for any binomial combination that satisfies the equation. And it can be extended to cubics, quartics, and I'm assuming all polynomial functions. Disclaimer: the symmetry can be lost with higher polynomials. I'm also assuming I'm not the first to notice this, but I was hoping someone smarter than me could run with it.

If the solution were too big to guess all you would have to do is create your own binomials then balance the equation based on the constant you added. And this method also works for irrationals. The binomials are not required to contain only integers.

Comment: I'm guessing the first line should read $x^2+5x+6=8$?

Comment: For simple equations such as yours, the complexity of guessing the solution is the same as for the original equation, using Vieta formula. For the more complicated equations, where solutions are either too big to guess, or even irrational, finding those values of $x$ that give identity above reduces to actually solving quadratic equation.

Comment: If the solution were too big to guess all you would have to do is create your own binomials then balance the equation based on the constant you added. And this method also works for irrationals. The binomials are not required to contain only integers.